# Strings as tick values for rCharts NVD3 line chart

Tags: r, rcharts, nvd3.js

I'm trying to use display categorical levels in the x-axis of my line chart. Say I have a data frame

```
mydata <- data.frame(time = c("10am", "12pm", "3pm"), month = c("JAN", "JUL", "DEC"), value = 3:5)
```

and I want to plot `value ~ time` or `value ~ month`. I could first create a variable that puts time on a linear scale, e.g.

```
mydata$time_linear <- 1:3
```

then try to plot

```
library(rCharts)
p <- nPlot(value ~ time_linear, data = mydata, type = "lineChart")
p$chart(useInteractiveGuideline = TRUE)
p
```

but I don't know how to force the labels.

I have looked at [How to set a nvd3 axis to use strings instead of numerical values ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648565/how-to-set-a-nvd3-axis-to-use-strings-instead-of-numerical-values) and [nvd3 line chart with string values on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727627/nvd3-line-chart-with-string-values-on-x-axis) but am not sure how it works in the context of `rCharts`. It seems like one way would be to define an array in javascript with the label names and index accordingly, and another would be to define a function with a bunch of `if/else` statements. The former method seems more elegant but I don't know how to conjure up an array in the right scope, and the latter would involve a nasty long anonymous function in `tickFormat`

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: What if you define `mydata$month` as Dates and then add `p$xAxis(tickFormat="#!function(d) {return d3.time.format('%b')(new Date( d * 86400000 ));}!#")`? ([via](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/nvd3/examples.R))

Comment: @lukeA thanks for the tip! This might just work for my purposes. Will test it out.

Comment: if this does not work, please reply and I will work something up.